# What is Visual Studio Keyboard Equivalent of Resharper F12 (Go to the next / previous highlight)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

When working with Resharper, I often used <kbd>F12</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to cycle through all the highlighted 'errors' found by Resharper.  That keystroke, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>  & <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> are my favorite way to fix errors quickly w/ Resharper.

I know you can do <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to fix the squiggly errors offered by the smart tags, but I need a faster way to navigate to any of them inside the editor.

**I am not looking for View.NextError which will allow you to jump to the next compilation / build error.**

Trying to find if Visual Studio 2010 has a similar shortcut, but no luck so far.

Anyone know?

Comment: Why not to add custom shortcuts for all commands you want?
By default F8 goes through errors as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

For some reason,  my VS2010 setup is using Visual Basic 6 keyboard scheme.
There is a **View.NextError** command, but it wasn't bound to anything.
Switched it Visual C# 2005 keyboard scheme and it's bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Great, now I can do TDD style development quicker.

All I need to do is quickly press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to go to the method / class that has not been implemented and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> to show the smart tag options or even better, binding the **OtherContextMenus.SmartTag.(whatever)** commands to some keystrokes to get more speed.

Remapping this keys to my usual Resharper settings might be nice.  Anyhow...